# Ios did receive memory warnings and application crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, crash, didreceivememorywarning

I'm new in IOS software development. I'm working on a new application with ARC. I'm Using Web services have added modules such as news and picture gallery.

I'm using picture slide in main activity with timer. But I'm getting memory warnings, and application finishes. I changed the resolution of the images which cames from web service. But the problem still continues. In practice, I use high quality designs. Viewer for iPhone 640 * 960 sizedesign I used in the photos. May be caused the design?

Comment: convert images into Jpeg representation with (0.1,your image). This will decrease the pixel rate of image and also size of image.

Comment: I used jpeg format at image from  web service.But the problem continues.

Comment: AND when I want to return to MainViewController,I dont use the navigation controller. MainViewController and the other viewControllers loading again. Is this caused by?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it could be due to the large images that you are showing i think in UIScrollView or UICollectionView or could be in UITableView whatever you are using
The memory warning is due to larger images.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

You can use the above code to change the size of Images.
like

```
[imageView setImage:[self imageWithImage:@"Image" scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
```

Or if you want you can rectify the code to use url of the image, these images will not produce memory warning.

Comment: which photos should resize. from Web services or  used for design ?

Comment: whichever you want to, if the images are larger the scrolling gets tough or in other case app may crash